# Jenkins doesn't notify after running docker compose up

Tags: spring-boot, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins to run my unit tests. Also, I am using docker-compose to link the spring boot and its Postgres database. Each time the Jenkins file is executed during a pull request or commit, I use the compose stack and to check that the tests have been performed correctly.
If the test fails then container aborted and Jenkins notifies but in a positive scenario when the spring boot application starts Jenkins doesn't notify and sticks.

this is the docker file :

```
FROM openjdk:10-jdk
COPY run.sh /
RUN chmod +x /run.sh
COPY ./target/*.jar /app.jar
CMD ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

This is the docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  app:
    restart: always
    build: .
    container_name: app
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - .:/app  
    ports:
      - 8085:8080
    links:
      - pgsql
    depends_on:
      - pgsql
  pgsql:
    image: postgres:10
    container_name: pgsql
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=passwordorsomething
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=pgsql
    restart: always
```

This is the stage for running docker compose and start spring boot and run the test :

```
      stage('Test') {
            agent {
                label "docker"
            }

            steps {

                sh 'docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)'
                sh 'docker-compose up --build --exit-code-from app'


            }
      }
```

After Jenkins reach to 'docker-compose up --build --exit-code-from app'  and the spring boot starts it sticks in the Test stage.

Comment: Were you able to get this fixed? I am also seeing a similar situation on Jenkins using `docker-compose run ...` to run a once-off command. I am not using `restart` and even though the command finishes, Jenkins is not able to see that it's completed and the job will hang until timeout.

Answer (score 0):

It's only a guess, but is the `restart: always` making the container restart. Assuming some of your tests are failing?

Its a good idea to add a post block to do `docker-compose down` to avoid zombie container

Comment: All the test unit pass, if some of them fail the container stops

Comment: You could do a `docker ps -a` on the host to see what his happening - is it continually restarting, for example